# Поддержка технологии PWA

Tags: веб-программирование, app

Chrome для iOS поддерживает технологию Progressive Web App для работы в фоновом режиме, например, для считывания скорости и пройденного расстояния, когда приложение не открыто?

Answer (score 0):

То о чем вы спрашиваете можно было бы реализовать с помощью  "service workers" которые используются в PWA. На данный момент поддерживаются синхронизация и push уведомления. Поддержку геолокации и подобных технологий обещают добавить в будущем.

Источники:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

https://techbeacon.com/how-use-service-workers-progressive-web-apps